# Initiate post save on Django abstract parent model, when child model saved

Tags: python, django, abstract-class

i have this models:

```
from django.db.models import Model

class SearchModel(Model):  
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Book(SearchModel):

    book_id = django_models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book'
```

I need that on `book.save()` a SearchModel function should be called (**without any code changes on Book/not creating post save signal on Book**)

My motivation is that every model inherit from SearchModel, will have some post_save handler (without writing extra code - only inherit Signal)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's quite simple: don't provide any specific "sender" when connecting your `post_save` handler, then in the handler check whether `sender` is a subclass of `SearchModel`, ie:

```
from django.db.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import Model

class SearchModel(Model):  
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def on_post_save(self):
        print "%s.on_post_save()" % self

# NB `SearchModel` already inherits from `Model` 
class Book(SearchModel):
    book_id = django_models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book'


@receiver(post_save)
def search_on_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if issubclass(sender, SearchModel):
         instance.on_post_save()
```

Then you can provide a default implementation in `SearchModel` and  override it if needed in subclasses.

Comment: is it necessary ? `class Book(Model, SearchModel)` ???? we can do this `class Book(SearchModel)`. is there any different ?

Comment: Nope, I just copy/pasted this part of the code but it should indeed be "`class Book(SearchModel)`". I edited my answer, thx.

Comment: yes its necessary, i just added here that both inherit from Model, but in actual it inherit from more classes

Comment: when your first class inherit from Model and second class inherit from first class, actually the second class inherit form Model too #eyal-ch

Comment: @EyalCh : the fact that `Book` may inherit from other classes too is irrelevant - if it inherits from `SearchModel` then _by definition_ it inherits from all the parent classes of `SearchModel` too - so *no* it's not required (only confusing) and it can even be problematic (depending on the base classes order) to make `Book` inherit from `Model`.

Comment: in actual Book is not inherit from Model (it inherit from internal Model).. i just added it her to be more simplified.

Comment: but it has a slight drawback, it gets called for every model that calls save()

Answer (score 4):

In your `signals.py`

```
from django.db.signals import post_save

def search_on_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    pass

for subclass in SearchModel.__subclasses__():
    post_save.connect(search_on_post_save, subclass)
```